# Do I need a graphics card on a headless system?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, headless

I'm planning to make a proper server this time around and I've been digging for proper parts all over the net. However, I'm still uncertain whether or not I'll be needing a graphics card for my system to function in the first place.

The parts I'm planning to use:

- [Intel Xeon E3-1231 V3](http://ark.intel.com/nl/products/80910/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1231-v3-8M-Cache-3_40-GHz)
- [Asus P9D-V](http://www.asus.com/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/P9DV/specifications/)

Requirements:

- RAID 5 on three 1TB SATA-600 drives
- ECC Memory
- Two ethernet ports
- Be a reliable, functional debian-based server

The specifications on the Asus website do say it has "onboard graphics" and it does feature a VGA port, yet I'm unsure whether or not this chip is an actual processor or just a throughput-kinda-thing that channels whatever comes from a PCI slot.

The only thing I would like to be able to see is terminal functionality. X11 stuff working would be nice but is definitely not required.

Also, if I'm completely missing the board here I would take some directions to a better approach very kindly.

Thank you for your time.

Edit: My question was not answered with the possible duplicate I was provided with because there was no answer to whether or not the system I envisioned, with the ASUS P9D-V, would work without a dedicated PCI graphics card.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/454972/does-a-modern-pc-require-a-graphics-card-to-run)

Comment: Yes, I read that, but there is no definitive answer. I would like someone to review my setup so I know for sure I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need a graphics card on a headless system?

No. Should you have it? Yes, probably. Or Remote Managment Features.

The board you mentioned ([Asus P9D-V](http://www.asus.com/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/P9DV/specifications/)) has a dedicated graphics processor.

*Graphic:     Aspeed AST1300 with 64MB VRAM*

> The only thing I would like to be able to see is terminal functionality. X11 stuff working would be nice but is definitely not required.

That will work with that GPU. In case something goes wrong you have the VGA port to locally debug the server with X11 (basic desktop, don't expect fancy 3D stuff) or CLI interface. If that is what you're looking for I would give that a go.

**Remote Managment Features**

You also need this VGA port (I would recommend it, in a serious setup) since the board has no remote features (like [KVM over IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_over_IP_.28IPKVM.29)) to adjust BIOS settings / review boot process.

This remote managment for server boards can be on-board (chipset integrated or dedicated) or achieved through a  commonly called BMC (Board Managment Card). What I found, Asus does not support this with your motherboard ([Asus UK FAQ](https://www.asus.com/uk/support/FAQ/1005657/)).
Sometimes the Chipset has this integrated, but the [Intel C224](http://ark.intel.com/products/75519/Intel-DH82C224-PCH) seems not (It is not *Intel vPro* enabled).

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. KVM or other remote access features to the hardware level are not required as it will probably be outdated by the time my data center is the size that would require those nifty features ;). Good to know this motherboard does have a gpu build in, as I really wasn't sure. It seems I'm good to go!  Thanks again!